# Combination of 3 coin flips

Tags: permutations, combinations

Friends, for 3 coin flips, the total possible outcomes are 8, given by 2x2x2. But if the order does not matter for me, i should find the combination, which is 4 (TTT, HHH, HHT, HTT).

For 3 coin flips, i can list out the 8 possible outcomes and cross out the repeats to find the number of combination. What if i am to do 10 coin flips? How can i find the number of combination w/o listing all possible outcomes and then crossing out the repeats?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

For $10$ coins, there is one configuration with $0$ head,  there is one configuration with $1$ head, one configuration with $2$ heads, one configuration with $3$ heads and so on. $\ldots$, one configuration with $10$ heads.

In general, if you have $n$ coins, you have $n+1$ combinations.

Comment: Thank you! An additional quick question: the 8 outcomes in 3 coinflips, do we call them permutations or combinations?

Comment: hmm... $THH$ and $HTT$ are different, so they can't be combinations.

Comment: Ya...so i guess if i call them combinations, people wouldn't get angry..i suppose

Comment: permutations cares about ordering, combinations doesn't. it should be permutations.

Comment: Got it! The 4 (TTT, HHH, HHT, HTT) can be called combination, but the 8 should be called permutations, since outcomes of same result but different different order (exp. THH, HHT) are counted in the 8.

Comment: @JorgeMercent in my opinion, I would reserve the names permutation and combination for things which are explicitly those.  For anything that is unclear which it is, I'd use a more generic term such as "arrangement" or "string."  I take issue with calling the eight outcomes "permutations" as permutations generally should use all available characters and have no repeats.  Unfortunately, "permutations" has gotten a double meaning of having the meaning of the more generic term of arrangement.

Comment: As for a more general approach to the question, some people would call this "combinations with repetition" or an "$n$-multisubset" and you can solve it with [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  It is a bit overkill for the specific problem of flipping a coin, but if you were rolling a $k$-sided die instead it will be quite relevant.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for mentioning stars-and-bars! It is mighty useful!